# How to store multiple values in an object using string as an indexer in c#?

Tags: c#, object

I've been going through this for hours now and just can't find a solution. I need to make a class that takes it's input like this:

```
Collection collection = new Collection(3);
collection("RandomNumber") = 123;
collection("DecimalNumber") = 456.78;
collection("Text") = "Hello world!";
```

The problem is whatever I try I won't get it working so that it would set and return all the values as supposed. Mostly I end up getting some errors that tell me that something cannot be converted to a string (while trying value.ToString() for an example).

All in all what I've done isn't that important because it didn't work, so can someone help me?

Comment: How about using a [`Dictionary<string, object>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: ...or an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx), if you'd like to keep the dots and avoid the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use a `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
Dictionary<string, object> collection = new Dictionary<string, object>(3);
collection["RandomNumber"] = 123;
collection["DecimalNumber"] = 456.78;
collection["Text"] = "Hello world!";

Console.WriteLine(collection["RandomNumber"]); // 123
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a beginner in c# and didn't know you could use object generally like that. Had to modify it a bit to make it work in the class but the important thing is that it worked.